# MySQL deadlocking issue with InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have a central database server and several "worker" servers which are executing queries like this concurrently:

```
UPDATE job_queue 
SET
  worker = '108.166.81.112',
  attempts = attempts + 1,
  started = '2014-01-14 10:34:03',
  token = '13eb3e6a8c3e1becb34051e08f19fd62'
WHERE completed = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  AND (started = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR started < '2014-01-14 10:29:03')
  AND attempts < 2
ORDER BY priority DESC, inserted
LIMIT 1
```

Occasionally my job_queue table locks up and if I run "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS", I get something like this:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
140114 10:34:15
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 46984514, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 590, OS thread id 140366633146112 fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 20 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 545 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 677401, query id 19385205 10.179.103.110 root init
UPDATE job_queue SET worker='108.166.81.112', attempts=attempts+1, started='2014-01-14 10:34:03', token='13eb3e6a8c3e1becb34051e08f19fd62' WHERE completed='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND (started='0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR started<'2014-01-14 10:29:03') AND attempts<2 ORDER BY priority DESC, inserted LIMIT 1
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 245767 n bits 128 index `PRIMARY` of table `database`.`job_queue` trx id 0 46984514 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 34 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 12; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 3; hex 800210; asc    ;; 1: len 6; hex 000002cced25; asc      %;; 2: len 7; hex 000003c00f1970; asc       p;; 3: len 30; hex 4f3a31343a2243425343616368654170704a6f62223a363a7b733a31393a; asc O:14:"CBSCacheAppJob":6:{s:19:;...(truncated); 4: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 5: len 8; hex 800012513c58bf24; asc    Q<X $;; 6: len 8; hex 800012513c58cc17; asc    Q<X  ;; 7: len 14; hex 31302e3137392e3130332e313333; asc 10.179.103.133;; 8: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 9: len 8; hex 800012513c58cc32; asc    Q<X 2;; 10: len 0; hex ; asc ;; 11: len 30; hex 353264393033616162656634346239626536306463346438666432303066; asc 52d903aabef44b9be60dc4d8fd200f;...(truncated);

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 46984485, ACTIVE 17 sec, process no 590, OS thread id 140366633547520 starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 676723, query id 19385209 10.179.103.133 root init
UPDATE job_queue SET worker='10.179.103.133', attempts=attempts+1, started='2014-01-14 10:34:03', token='efd21d0d34f44badbc30386db4dd252e' WHERE completed='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND (started='0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR started<'2014-01-14 10:29:03') AND attempts<2 ORDER BY priority DESC, inserted LIMIT 1
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 245767 n bits 128 index `PRIMARY` of table `database`.`job_queue` trx id 0 46984485 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 34 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 12; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 3; hex 800210; asc    ;; 1: len 6; hex 000002cced25; asc      %;; 2: len 7; hex 000003c00f1970; asc       p;; 3: len 30; hex 4f3a31343a2243425343616368654170704a6f62223a363a7b733a31393a; asc O:14:"CBSCacheAppJob":6:{s:19:;...(truncated); 4: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 5: len 8; hex 800012513c58bf24; asc    Q<X $;; 6: len 8; hex 800012513c58cc17; asc    Q<X  ;; 7: len 14; hex 31302e3137392e3130332e313333; asc 10.179.103.133;; 8: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 9: len 8; hex 800012513c58cc32; asc    Q<X 2;; 10: len 0; hex ; asc ;; 11: len 30; hex 353264393033616162656634346239626536306463346438666432303066; asc 52d903aabef44b9be60dc4d8fd200f;...(truncated);

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 57 n bits 120 index `PRIMARY` of table `database`.`job_queue` trx id 0 46984485 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 12; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 3; hex 800001; asc    ;; 1: len 6; hex 000002ccdab1; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 000003c0352b3f; asc     5+?;; 3: len 30; hex 4f3a31323a224175746f50696c6f744a6f62223a363a7b733a31383a2200; asc O:12:"AutoPilotJob":6:{s:18:" ;...(truncated); 4: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 5: len 8; hex 800012513c58af57; asc    Q<X W;; 6: len 8; hex 800012513c58bf22; asc    Q<X ";; 7: len 14; hex 3130382e3136362e38312e313132; asc 108.166.81.112;; 8: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 9: len 8; hex 800012513c58bf23; asc    Q<X #;; 10: len 0; hex ; asc ;; 11: len 30; hex 616331376430346339326163613366323330646164323239363764336266; asc ac17d04c92aca3f230dad22967d3bf;...(truncated);

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 46989905
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 46986227 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 24
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, process no 590, OS thread id 140366628529920
MySQL thread id 703864, query id 20047015 localhost root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 0 46989894, not started, process no 590, OS thread id 140366636758784
MySQL thread id 702822, query id 20046897 10.179.1.63 root
---TRANSACTION 0 46986223, ACTIVE 39782 sec, process no 590, OS thread id 140366626322176
25 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 710 row lock(s), undo log entries 9
MySQL thread id 677706, query id 19994505 10.179.103.114 root
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 46986224, sees < 0 46986224
```

Any further writes to the table then time out on me until I restart my MySQL server (or manually kill the deadlocked jobs):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction(Query: "UPDATE job_queue SET worker='108.166.81.250', attempts=attempts+1, started='2014-01-14 21:27:45', token='369eae55a7f0eacad3b678a3410de8e4' WHERE completed='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND (started='0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR started<'2014-01-14 21:22:45') AND attempts<2 ORDER BY priority DESC, inserted LIMIT 1") in /utilities/Database.php on line 53
```

Can anyone explain to me why this query causes a deadlock?  I was under the impression that all queries on an InnoDB table happened atomically.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is causing a deadlock because the `UPDATE` query is locking all rows in the table, and depending on the indexes used (or lack thereof), two different sessions will potentially lock them in slightly different order. Remember that `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` will lock all rows they encounter, whether those rows match all `WHERE` conditions or not. So when using them, you should try hard to be sure that they encounter as few rows as possible, by using indexes (ideally the primary key) and avoiding vague or wide-selecting conditions.

My suggestion for work queues is pretty much universal: Lock as little as possible as rarely as possible and always in a deterministic order. So, generally:

1. Use non-locking reads (regular `SELECT`) to find work to do by looking for stuff your worker knows how to do and is currently unclaimed (`lease_owner IS NULL AND lease_expiry IS NULL` -- or similar).
2. Choose one work item (or a few if you dare, but one is far simpler and normally allows for perfectly acceptable performance).
3. Update your work item (to claim it, but for any case it needs updating as well):

   1. Open a transaction.
   2. Lock your chosen work item with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` -- If it is no longer unclaimed, abort and choose another.
   3. Update your chosen work item with your worker id and an expiry time for your lease on it.
   4. Commit your transaction immediately.
4. Begin work on your leased work items.
5. In some other process, another poller looks for abandoned work and un-claims it (via the same update process above).

You can easily get very high throughput with this design (thousands of jobs per second), and with essentially no contention and no ordering issues. Optimizations to choose work that is less likely to conflict with other pollers are simple and effective (e.g. modulus on Job ID or similar, chosen to avoid starvation of jobs). The key is to remember that conflict on job selection is *okay* -- just abort and try again and everything moves along very quickly.

All locking writes for work queue items/jobs should be done only on *single rows* and by primary key *only*.